# Solving the following equation

Tags: problem-solving

What is the easiest way to solve the following equation **for g in terms of x**? I seem to be going in circles, and don't know how exactly to deal with the $\pm$ symbol.

**Equation:** $$\pm \sqrt{2}x + \ln(2\sqrt{6}+1)= \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{g+2}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{g+2}+\sqrt{3}}\right|$$

I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take it apart step by step: first exponentiate both sides:
$$e^{\rm LHS}=\frac{\sqrt{g+2}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{g+2}+\sqrt{3}}\ .$$
Multiply out,
$$e^{\rm LHS}(\sqrt{g+2}+\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{g+2}-\sqrt{3}\ ,$$
expand, now you should easily be able to find $\sqrt{g+2}$, then square and subtract $2$.